# how do I select the following DOM items?

Tags: jquery

[image]

I want to select the highlighted items so that I can turn them green:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
         $('????').css("color", "green");
     });
</script>
```

Can somebody give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the element by it's class.

so `$('.k-in')` should do this

Putting it in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.k-in').css("color", "green");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: @Rj. did you do it in dom ready or whether the contents are generated dynamically or loaded after the dom ready

Comment: The contents of this DIV are loaded based on a separate JavaScript file which I put at the top of the page. <script src="../Scripts/RelationshipsTreeView.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.k-in').css("color", "green");
});
```

As noted, it is advised to use css for styling. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HNURW/) example. You will see if a page takes longer to load, the second div that is styled with jQuery has black text first, because it takes a while for the jQ to be executed.

Comment: Could you perhaps put it in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) then? The code seems to be correct.

Comment: I suspect the tree is being generated with javascript, and you're applying that too soon (before the nodes exist)

Comment: @Rj. : It waits until the page is loaded and then updates the css, but if the element is injected with js after the page is loaded it will not work.

Comment: @Rj. Just add it to your CSS stylesheet.

Comment: @arbitter, I think thats my issue. let me check and ill report back.

Comment: I would also suggest just adding it in css, Doesn't really have a point to add it later with jQuery right after the page has loaded.